# Freeze Panes in multiple worksheets C#

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I am working on MS Excel 2013 generating report where all the worksheets in workbook should have freeze pane at column 6 and row 1. I have searched on Google but could not find any solution as for freezing the pane, workbook has to be active. I have tried a lot of things but no success. I will really appreciate if someone can help me.

```
Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open("filelocation");

foreach (Excel.Worksheet ws in workbook.Worksheets)
{
    ws.Application.ActiveWindow.SplitColumn = 6;
    ws.Application.ActiveWindow.SplitRow = 1;
    ws.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = true;
}

excel.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I Hope it help others. I have used ClosedXML Library for Excel and after creating each worksheet I used

```
worksheet.SheetView.Freeze(1,6);
```

This freezes the Row 1, Col 6. You can freeze any row/column.
Here is link to [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/). It's widely supported and very good documentation.

Answer (score 2):

To freeze the panes on each worksheet you need to modify your for loop to add a line to activate the current sheet prior to setting the other properties. Here is my solution:

```
Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open("filelocation");

foreach (Excel.Worksheet ws in workbook.Worksheets)
{
    ws.Activate();
    ws.Application.ActiveWindow.SplitColumn = 6;
    ws.Application.ActiveWindow.SplitRow = 1;
    ws.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = true;
}

excel.Visible = true;
```